# Go to next symbol if appears in current line and if not go to end of line

Tags: vim

Suppose that I have the following line of code, and the cursor is placed where the `^` symbol is:

```
if i == 3: print()
     ^
```

I want to make an nmap such that the cursor goes to the `:` but that particular symbol is missing, for example if the code is:

```
if i == 3
```

then it should go to the end of the line. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try searching for either `:` or the end of the line:

```
:nnoremap <C-e> /:\\|$<CR>
```

Add a `:nohl<CR>` at the end to disable highlighting for this search.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't thinking of using `/` or `?` but `f` and `F`. What are the `\(` and `\)` for?

Comment: It is a clever usage of `/ or ?`.  Note that, a) this will overwrite the  `/` register, it will bring you to `: or $(EOL)` when you press `n or N` next time. 2) `<c-e>` is useful key-combination in normal mode, it scrolls the buffer down. maybe another short key consideration is better. 3) in regex, the grouping `\( and \)` could be saved. However this is a good answer, so +1

Comment: In case you do not want the search register to change: `nnoremap <key> :call search(':\|$', '', line('.'))<cr>`

Comment: @JavierGarcia You're right, I added the grouping without thinking too much. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

As Mihai pointed out this is possible, but I think you should not use a mapping for this.

Press `f:` if the `:` is present ("find :"), else just press `$` ("end of line") - this keeps your `.vimrc` clean, you waste no mapping and can profit from these builtin commands in other ways, e.g. `d$` ("delete till end of line"), `cf:` ("change text till including the :") and so on.

It also saves you a keystroke if the `:` is not present because you only press one key :)